# IOException when using proguard apk

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm new to proguard I use Dagger2 + Retrofit + rxjava + autoValue Gson in my app

when I enable Proguard I **sometimes** get **IOException(No Internet connection..)**

I apply proguard rules to model class of my app plus the third party libraries

My Proguard rules files is:

[Proguard rules](https://gist.github.com/alihabbash/e1298045b501318e7f395572b05a5fc2)

**Edit:**

I decompile my APK to see how proguard obfuscate & I see this to all POJO classes:

```
@SerializedName(a = "title")
public abstract String title();
```

Comment: Make sure all your DTO objects have `@SerializedName` annotation, otherwise proguard obfuscates the DTO fields.

Comment: I edited the question.